# Linear Regression using Scikit-learn vs Statsmodels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I wanted to check if a Multiple Linear Regression problem produced the same output when solved using Scikit-Learn and Statsmodels.api. I did it in 3 sections (in the order of their mention): Statsmodels(without intercept), Statsmodels(with intercept) and SKL. As expected, my SKL coefficients and R(square) were as same as that of Statsmodels(with intercept) but my SKL mean square error was equivalent to that of Statsmodels(without intercept).

I am going to share my notebook code; it's a fairly basic piece of code, since I have just started with Machine Learning Applications. Please go through it and tell me why it is happening. Also, if you could share your insights on any inefficient piece of code, I would be thankful. Here's the code:

https://github.com/vgoel60/Linear-Regression-using-Sklearn-vs-Statsmodel.api/blob/master/Linear%20Regression%20Boston%20Housing%20Prices%20using%20Scikit-Learn%20and%20Statsmodels.api.ipynb

Comment: Do you realize the link points to a local server running on your computer? It cannot be accessed by others. Post your code in the body.

Comment: Damn! No, I didn't realise that. I've never used any applications on local servers; the way Jupyter notebooks work on my computer. I'll just post the code in the body.

Comment: I created a Github account and uploaded this code there. It should work fine now. Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, which explains the strange results. When you make the predictions from the linear model with scikit-learn, you write:

```
predictions2 = lm.predict(xtest2)
```

Notice that you are using the `lm` model, the one resulting from the first statsmodels regression. Instead, you should have written:

```
predictions2 = lm2.predict(xtest2)
```

When you do this, the results are as expected.

Comment: That answers my problem. Thank you very much.